# Logstash file is missing in /etc/init.d after installing logstash ubuntu

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

I am installing logstash 6.3.0 in Ubuntu with the following commands

curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/logstash/logstash-6.3.0.deb
sudo dpkg -i logstash-6.3.0.deb

Although the installation is completed, Still no logstash file will be created in /etc/init.d directory and therefore having issues in starting logstash

But when I install a lower version with the following URL and it creates the file successfully
https://download.elastic.co/logstash/logstash/packages/debian/logstash_2.3.4-1_all.deb

What is the exact reason for that and are there any place to get an .deb file of 6.3 logstash ??

Answer (score 1):

If the service for Logstash 6.3 wasn't created for some reason, you can recreate it. Try the following.

Edit the file `/etc/logstash/startup.options` and put the location of the `java` binary and the java installation, like the example below.

```
JAVACMD=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_161
```

Now go to `/user/share/logstash/bin` and run the `system-install` script.

```
sudo ./system-install
```

It should give you the message: `Successfully created system startup script for Logstash`