# /etc/init.d/logstash file not created for RHEL 6.8

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, rhel, rhel6

I downloaded `logstash-6.4.0.rpm` and  Installed  with

```
yum install logstash-6.4.0.rpm
```

for **RHEL 6.8** but `etc/init.d/logstash`

After installation, I got a message

```
Successfully created system startup script for Logstash
```

But the file is not created, it is autogenerated for SysV [See here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash.html#running-logstash-sysv)

I tried generating manually by editing `/etc/logstash/startup.options` added like this

```
JAVACMD=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_111
```

and then went to `/user/share/logstash/bin` and ran `sudo ./system-install`  [Saw Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612113/logstash-file-is-missing-in-etc-init-d-after-installing-logstash-ubuntu)

After executing `sudo ./system-install` again got same message

```
Successfully created system startup script for Logstash
```

But still, the file is not created. Any idea, how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to generate the logstash service I was missing some options in the command.

> step 1: check where your logstash is with command `whereis logstash` >  for me :

```
[root@user ~]# whereis logstash
logstash: /etc/logstash /usr/share/logstash
```

> step 2: edit `/etc/logstash/startup.options` file and correct path for `JAVACMD` and  `JAVA_HOME`

```
JAVACMD=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_111
```

> step 3: Go to `/usr/share/logstash/bin` and  run `system-install` with `sudo`

```
sudo ./system-install /etc/logstashstartup.options sysv
```

> Result

```
[root@user bin]# sudo ./system-install /etc/logstash/startup.options sysv
Using provided startup.options file: /etc/logstash/startup.options
Manually creating startup for specified platform: sysv
Successfully created system startup script for Logstash
```